# How can I pass a JSON object to a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, json-rpc, web3-providers

let's say I have a JSON object containing addresses and token balances as key pairs:

`{"0x0...":"10", "0x0...":50, "0x0...":200}`

I'm building a smart contract that needs to receive individual address/balance pairs from this single JSON object, and store them (preferably an array)

What would be the best way to do this?